# Is it possible to draw this specific complete bipartite Graph?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Is it possible to draw a complete bipartite graph which has $10$ vertices and $20$ edges, if so then draw?

-I am thinking not, since in a complete graph all vertices are connected to every other edge so an action to separate these edges, connecting them without them colliding in their own subsets V$1$ and V$2$ would seem impossible to me, i may be wrong.

Comment: What meaning are you attaching to "draw" here? It seems to me that the question might be simply asking "Does there exist a complete bipartite graph with $10$ vertices and $20$ edges?"

Comment: The meaning is this: if that graph exists then draw it, so show it in a graphical way

Comment: "In a complete graph every edge is connected to every other edge"  What?

Comment: In that case, unless you are claiming "complete bipartite graphs never exist" then you should be using some properties of $10$ and $20$ somewhere in your argument.

Comment: I meant every vertices is connected to every edge, it means there's a incidence edge for every set of vertices in the graph, sorry

Comment: Also i think it may not exist, i am not sure but if it exists i need your help on how to prove it!

Answer (score 1):

The complete bipartite graph $K_{a,b}$ has $a+b$ vertices and $ab$ edges. So you need $a,b$ with $a+b=10$ and $ab=20$. Also for purposes of this question, $K_{a,b} = K_{b,a}$. From the second constraint, we have that $a$ and $b$ must be $(1,20), (2,10),$ or $(4,5)$. Since none of these sum to 10, there is no such complete bipartite graph.